# Randomly assign array value with another array's value

Tags: c#, arrays, list, random

How do I assign one set of array values with another array's values? Both have 26 values.

I'm emulating a Deal or No Deal game where the user chooses a case from a specified list. Now, on each run of the console app I want there to be a random assignment for each cash prize to each case (for fairness sakes). My code is of the following:

```
    int[] cashPrizeArray = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 500, 750, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 10000, 15000, 20000, 25000, 50000, 75000, 100000, 200000 };
    string[] caseArray = new string[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26" };

    Console.WriteLine("Deal or Not!");
    Console.Write("Choose a case: 1-26: ");
    string userCase = Console.ReadLine();



    if (!caseArray.Contains(userCase))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nUnexpected input text.\nThis application will now be terminated.\nPress ENTER to continue...");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }

    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You chose case " + userCase);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

I will need to reference these cases one by one when a user chooses them, and then remove them from being called in the array once initially opened.

Comment: And you have a question?

Comment: Search for `shuffle c#` dozens and dozens of answers here ready and waiting for you to find them

Comment: @Enigmativity How do I assign one set of array values with another array's values? Both have 26 values.

Comment: @kzone95: It's not clear to me what you even mean by "assign one set of array values with another array's values".  So far your program has two arrays and accepts one input value from the user.  Is something not working in that code?  If your code is working and you're looking to move on to your next step, what is that step?  Logically break down the problem into small and specific pieces.  Which piece are you trying next?  What have you tried?

Comment: Define a field in your class `private static Random _rnd = new Random();` then on the line after you have defined `cashPrizeArray` put this: `cashPrizeArray = cashPrizeArray.OrderBy(x => _rnd.Next()).ToArray();`.

Answer (score 0):

If you make a 2D list with the first dimension showing what case and the second dimension showing the amount of money for that amount of money. Then you check if you already have
used that specific case and if so then try again(used goto but you can change) or if it hasn't been used then you add that case into the list along with the money in the second dimension.

Code:

```
public static List<List<string>> PairedCases = new List<List<string>>();

    public static void addsubstrin(string money, string casenom)
    {
        List<string> sublist = new List<string>();

        sublist.Add(money);
        sublist.Add(casenom);

        PairedCases.Add(sublist);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] cashPrizeArray = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 500, 750, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 10000, 15000, 20000, 25000, 50000, 75000, 100000, 200000 };
        string[] caseArray = new string[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26" };

        Random rnd = new Random();

        foreach (int inte in cashPrizeArray)
        {
            Restart:;

            int putincase = rnd.Next(1, 27);

            bool found = false;

            //here we chack if its already in the list

            for (int a = 0; a < PairedCases.Count(); a++)
            {
                if (putincase.ToString() == PairedCases[a][1])
                {
                    found = true;
                }
            }

            if(found == false)
            {
                addsubstrin(inte.ToString(), putincase.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                goto Restart;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < PairedCases.Count(); i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(PairedCases[i][0] + "   " + PairedCases[i][1]);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```